# can implement UITapGestureRecognizer with array of image view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

UITapGestureRecognizer can implement with array of image? can it work same as single image?
how it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on a single view. You will have to use a single recognizer per view.

You can however use the same target-action pair to handle all the gesture recognizers. If you are looking for the gesture to behave the same way for all the image views then this is the easiest thing to do. If the action must identify the view and handle it appropriately, you can use the `view` property to complete the appropriate action.

If you are looking for how gesture recognizers work, read [`this`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).

Comment: i have array of image in scroll view so i apply this for zoom every image.